# AWS Lambda using API Gateway error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Everything was working yesterday and I'm simply still testing so my capacity shouldn't be high to begin with but I keep receiving these errors today:

> {
>       Message = "We currently do not have sufficient capacity in the region you requested. Our system will be working on provisioning
>   additional capacity. You can avoid getting this error by temporarily
>   reducing your request rate.";
>   Type =Service; 
>   }

What is this error message and should I be concerned that something like this would happen when I go into production? This is a serious error because my users are mandated to login using calls to api gateway (utilizing aws lambda).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error should not last long as it will immediately trigger AWS provision request.

If you concern about your api gateway availbility, consider to create redundant lambda function on other regions and switch whenever this error occurs. However calling lambda from a remote region can introduce long latency.

Comment: how would I implement the redundant lambda functions? Can I have something in the backend that says switch the region used if x error occurs, or is this more along front-end implementation?

Comment: Simply upload your code to another region and create the same function. In your front end check the error msg and switch

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is, please review the aws limits for API gateway and Lambda services in your account. If your requests do exceed the limits, raise ticket to aws to extend it.

```
Amazon API Gateway Limits

Resource    Default Limit
Maximum APIs per AWS account    60
Maximum resources per API   300
Maximum labels per API  10
```

Increase the limits is free service in aws.

Refer: [Amazon API Gateway Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_apigateway)

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda posted an event on the [service health dashboard](http://status.aws.amazon.com/), so please follow this for further details on that specific issue.

Unfortunately, if you want to return a custom code when Lambda errors in this way you would have to write a mapping template and attach it to every integration response where you used a Lambda integration.

We recognize that this is suboptimal and is work most customers would prefer API Gateway just handle for them. With that in mind, we already have a high priority item on our backlog to make it easier to pass through the status codes from the Lambda integration. I cannot, however, commit to a timeframe as to when this would be available.